# Unable to get rid of orphan temporary tables

Tags: mysql, mariadb

After migrating from MariaDB 5.5 to 10.0, I noticed an error message mentioning a table named `piwik/#sql-1526_3a`.

From there I started googling and landed on the [innodb troubleshooting docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html#innodb-orphan-temporary-tables)

Indeed, `SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INNODB_SYS_TABLES WHERE NAME LIKE '%#sql%';` gives the following result:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INNODB_SYS_TABLES WHERE NAME LIKE '%#sql%';
+----------+--------+----------------+------+--------+-------+
| TABLE_ID | SCHEMA | NAME           | FLAG | N_COLS | SPACE |
+----------+--------+----------------+------+--------+-------+
|      323 | piwik  | #sql-1526_3a   |    1 |     11 |   320 |
|      265 | piwik  | #sql-5305_92b0 |    1 |     24 |   262 |
|      321 | piwik  | #sql-7920_48   |    1 |     24 |   318 |
+----------+--------+----------------+------+--------+-------+
```

I tried to follow MySQL troubleshooting instructions and did:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> use piwik
Database changed
MariaDB [piwik]> drop table `#mysql50##sql-1526_3a`;
ERROR 1051 (42S02): Unknown table '#mysql50##sql-1526_3a'
```

From there, I read more blog posts and stack exchange answers and noticed that there are no `#sql-1526_3a.idb` and `#sql-1526_3a.frm` files in my `/var/lib/mysql/piwik/` folder.

I then tried the following:

```
$ cd /var/lib/mysql/piwik
$ cp piwik_user.ibd #sql-1526_3a.ibd
$ cp piwik_user.frm #sql-1526_3a.frm
```

and restarted MariaDB.

Then I tried droping the table again:

```
MariaDB [piwik]> drop table `#mysql50##sql-1526_3a`;
Database changed
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00sec)
```

Horray?!! Well, `SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INNODB_SYS_TABLES WHERE NAME LIKE '%#sql%';` still lists the `#sql-1526_3a` table. On disk, the `.frm` file got deleted but the `.ibd` file remains.

So? Does someone know how I can remove these orphan tables for real?

---

**EDIT**

It seems to me these trailing temporary tables are "referenced" from `/var/lib/mysql/ibdata1` before I shrunk it and enabled `innodb_file_per_table = 1`.

Comment: I think you borked your catalog. Good luck. You may be able to dump reload to work around the problem.

Comment: When you say dump reload, do you mean dump the db to file, drop, then reimport?

Answer (score 0):

This may work -- I found it interesting in any event:  [How to remove Temp Tables the proper way](https://mariadb.com/resources/blog/get-rid-orphaned-innodb-temporary-tables-right-way)

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. I tried it before posting :(